# keep post variable in php pagination

Tags: php, pagination, paging

I have a php pagination page with post submit by user to search something, query mysql in first page is ok, but in NEXT page, i have get white blank page.

Below is the paging code.

```
$_SESSION['nationality'] = $_POST['nationality'];
$reclimit = 2;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
$page = 1;
}

$start = (($page-1) * $reclimit);

$sql = "SELECT userid, name, LEFT(hkid, 4) as hkid, description, nationality, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3 FROM $tbl_name WHERE `nationality` LIKE '%$_SESSION[nationality]%'";
$records = $con->query($sql);

$total = $records->num_rows;
$tpages = ceil($total / $reclimit);

$rec = "SELECT userid, name, LEFT(hkid, 4) as hkid, description, nationality, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3 FROM $tbl_name WHERE `nationality` LIKE '%$_SESSION[nationality]%' LIMIT $start, $reclimit";
$records = $con->query($rec);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

// Loop record

}

// Paging
echo '<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">';
for( $i=1; $i <= $tpages; $i++ ) {
$active = $i == $page ? 'class="active"' : '';
echo "<li $active ><a href='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=" .$i. "'>" .$i. "</a></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php 
 $limit =3;
if (!isset($_GET['pg'])) {
    $pg = 1;
} else {
    $pg = $_GET['pg'];
}
$start = ($pg - 1 ) * $limit;                        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName LIMIT $start , $limit";
?>
```

Comment: @HalaAtef your post is not an answer since in it, you focus on the start and end of the pagination but not on the question about how to keep _post_ (i.e. $_POST) when switching pages!